# How to see the total bandwidth a process has used since it was started?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, bandwidth, file-server

I am currently watching some process on my server and want to see how much bandwidth it has **used in total** since it has been started. I don't want to know its current usage, nor does `nethogs` / `nload` help me.

Answer (score 8):

See my [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1291285/227233).

> You can use nethog with total bandwidth monitored per MB since it
>   started with:
>
> `sudo nethogs -v 3`

Answer (score 3):

Funny question. It seems you can see snmp values of a process in `/proc/[pid]/net/dev_snmp6/[DEV]` at least for IP6:

```
ifIndex                             4
Ip6InReceives                       4
Ip6InHdrErrors                      0
Ip6InTooBigErrors                   0
Ip6InNoRoutes                       0
Ip6InAddrErrors                     0
Ip6InUnknownProtos                  0
Ip6InTruncatedPkts                  0
Ip6InDiscards                       0
Ip6InDelivers                       4
Ip6OutForwDatagrams                 0
Ip6OutRequests                      24
Ip6OutDiscards                      0
Ip6OutNoRoutes                      0
Ip6ReasmTimeout                     0
Ip6ReasmReqds                       0
Ip6ReasmOKs                         0
Ip6ReasmFails                       0
Ip6FragOKs                          0
Ip6FragFails                        0
Ip6FragCreates                      0
Ip6InMcastPkts                      2
Ip6OutMcastPkts                     34
Ip6InOctets                         618
Ip6OutOctets                        1946
Ip6InMcastOctets                    304
Ip6OutMcastOctets                   2786
Ip6InBcastOctets                    0
Ip6OutBcastOctets                   0
Ip6InNoECTPkts                      4
Ip6InECT1Pkts                       0
Ip6InECT0Pkts                       0
Ip6InCEPkts                         0
Icmp6InMsgs                         2
Icmp6InErrors                       0
Icmp6OutMsgs                        22
Icmp6OutErrors                      0
Icmp6InCsumErrors                   0
Icmp6InDestUnreachs                 0
Icmp6InPktTooBigs                   0
Icmp6InTimeExcds                    0
Icmp6InParmProblems                 0
Icmp6InEchos                        0
Icmp6InEchoReplies                  0
Icmp6InGroupMembQueries             0
Icmp6InGroupMembResponses           0
Icmp6InGroupMembReductions          0
Icmp6InRouterSolicits               0
Icmp6InRouterAdvertisements         2
Icmp6InNeighborSolicits             0
Icmp6InNeighborAdvertisements       0
Icmp6InRedirects                    0
Icmp6InMLDv2Reports                 0
Icmp6OutDestUnreachs                0
Icmp6OutPktTooBigs                  0
Icmp6OutTimeExcds                   0
Icmp6OutParmProblems                0
Icmp6OutEchos                       0
Icmp6OutEchoReplies                 0
Icmp6OutGroupMembQueries            0
Icmp6OutGroupMembResponses          0
Icmp6OutGroupMembReductions         0
Icmp6OutRouterSolicits              9
Icmp6OutRouterAdvertisements        0
Icmp6OutNeighborSolicits            3
Icmp6OutNeighborAdvertisements      0
Icmp6OutRedirects                   0
Icmp6OutMLDv2Reports                10
Icmp6InType134                      2
Icmp6OutType133                     9
Icmp6OutType135                     3
Icmp6OutType143                     10
```

but quite likely that is a special kernel feature I eventually compiled in.

```
cat /proc/3553/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0: 23650521  158896    0    0    0     0          0      9457   720802    4696    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo:   53621     490    0    0    0     0          0         0    53621     490    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

By querying the `net/dev` file in `/proc/[pid]`. You can read the IO bytes for each used interface.

The bandwidth needs to be divided by the uptime of the process, which can be found by `clock(3)`. But there might be other methods to find the start time of the process.

It seems to me, that `stat /proc/[pid]` might be quite exact and also `/proc/[pid]/stat` contains the time in clock ticks since system start.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately this is a little late now because we had to continue our work, killing the process. But I know this will be helpful some time. Seems to be quite tricky to do this though ;) Best advice would be to run some kind of network monitoring as a "default" on a Linux server right after installation.

Comment: The network monitoring is no problem. But it's hard get the network io for a process. I was astonished to find something for ipv6. Your best bet is to setup a virtual network for a process and monitor the virtual interface.

Comment: Which values to look for here? Also, how can I find which ID to look for instead of "pid" ?